# How to save data to mysql via python

Tags: python, mysql

I am working on a program using EEL project framework for python and in my html I have a register form, but I cannot seem to get data going through to mysql database which is remote, so I am using a tunneler. Connection is established so no issues with that, the data just does not save.

Here is a part of my code

```
@eel.expose
def register_button(token, email, mpass):
     myToken = format(token)
     myEmail = format(email)
     myPass = format(mpass)
     if myToken == '':
          print('token is empty')
     elif myEmail == '':
          print('email is empty')
     elif myPass == '':
          print('password is empty')
   else:
    server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
        'X.X.X.X',
        ssh_username='user',
        ssh_password='pass',
        remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306)
    )
    server.start()

    myDB = mysql.connector.connect(
        host='127.0.0.1',
        port=server.local_bind_port,
        user='user',
        password='pass',
        db='db'
    )
    myCursor = myDB.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT `iduser` FROM `uuids` WHERE `myuuid` = '%s'" % myToken
    myCursor.execute(sql)
    results = myCursor.fetchone()
    if results:
        iduserDB = results[0]
        if iduserDB is None:
            print('id is null')
            sql5 = "SELECT `email` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '%s'" % myEmail
            myCursor.execute(sql5)
            resultz = myCursor.fetchone()
            if resultz:
                emailDB = resultz[0]
                if emailDB is None:
                    sql2 = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES (%s, %s)"
                    val = (myEmail, myPass)
                    myCursor.execute(sql2, val)
                    myDB.commit()
                    lastRowID = myCursor.lastrowid
                    sql3 = "UPDATE `uuids` SET `iduser` = %i WHERE `uuids` = %s"
                    val3 = (lastRowID, myToken)
                    myCursor.execute(sql3, val3)
                    myDB.commit()
                else:
                    print('email is already in use')
        else:
            print('id is not null')
    else:
        return False
    myDB.close()
    server.stop()
return 'Thank you for registering!'
```

The concept is simple, basically take the data from the front end and then just see if the token already exists in the uuid database, if it does not exist, then just move forward and check if the email exists in the database, if it doesn't then only then go and insert the data.

I am new to Python, any help would be greatly appreciated. Forgive the indent, in pycharm is how it should, is just the structuring here with copy paste.

Comment: I think i might be able to do one big sql query with join instead of two, when i do the checkup, but I am interested to see if this is the correct way to go. Thanks

Comment: I'm curious about how you assign the strings to sq12 and sq13 variables. Is your myCursor.execute() command really replacing it with the other vars values?

Comment: @Tané that can be a possibility of why is not working, I am a newbie when it comes to python, I admit. I will check on that. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Tané I created new cursors for each sql query and still not saving...